# Given two large corpora of text from different sources, is there an accepted way to get differences in vocabulary (n-grams) between them?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, tfidf

Given two large corpora of text from different sources, is there an accepted way to get differences in vocabulary (n-grams) between them?

That is, to get results which say that, for example, the bigram "hello world" is much more common in corpus A than corpus B (ideally with some kind of measure of how much more common).

TF-IDF examples use a larger number of documents to highlight "important" words in each, but I am not sure if that would work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question you can work with `NLTK`.

Have a look on the following functions:

- Tokenize
- Stemmers
- pos_tags (if you wanna categorize by Verb, Noun etc. beforehand)

And to come to your question of similarity or relative word/phrase usage you have `FreqDist`function in NLTK. Using this Output you could set each occurance relative to the length of the list that is returned by `tokenize`